# Why is nested tidyr function inconsistently generating error?

Tags: r, loops, tidyverse, tidyr

I have written two functions (one nested in the other), one of which is inconsistently throwing an error, such that I've struggling to identity where to even begin with troubleshooting.

To describe each function briefly:

- `importJSON()` has been written to use jsonlite::`fromJSON()` and tidyverse:: functions to scrape data from individual .json files containing multiple observations of day-level data about a person, within which there are several observations of 30-sec epoch event-level data, which are then returned in a tidied data frame; it's not intended to be called directly by users
- `scrapePerson()` is intended to be called directly by users, and deploys importJSON() on a particular person's folder of data, scraping the data day-level and event-level data (which requiring unnesting), and using `rbind()` to combine all the data frames (for each .json file) into one tidied data frame

`importJSON()` seems to work on all cases I tested it on, and `scrapePerson()`, likewise, has worked on most. For one folder of data, however, the function has thrown the following error:

> Error in `list_unchop()`: ! Can't combine `x[[36]]` <data.frame> and
> `x[[37]]` .
>
> --- Backtrace:
>
> 1. snoozr::scrapePerson(...)
> 2. snoozr::importJSON(newpath, level1 = TRUE)
>    at snoozr/R/scrapePerson.R:82:6
> 3. tidyr:::unnest.data.frame(fjson.df, levels.shortData, names_sep = ".")
> 4. tidyr::unchop(data, any_of(cols), keep_empty = keep_empty, ptype = ptype)
> 5. tidyr:::df_unchop(cols, ptype = ptype, keep_empty = keep_empty)
> 6. vctrs::vec_unchop(col, ptype = col_ptype)
> 7. vctrs::list_unchop(...)

Being a largely self-trained programmer, I tried to debug this the only way I know how: the painstakingly monotonous way, applying `importJSON()` individually to each of the 66 .json files in the problematic folder, and using `rbind()` to iteratively stitch them together into one data frame, in the same manner the `scrapePerson()` function would.

To my surprise, this worked without any error (e.g., my expectations had been that it might struggle to combine data from the 37th .json to the `rbind()`'ed 1-36th .json files).

Does anyone have an intuition of what might be happening here? The interior of `importJSON()` seems to be working just fine on the files in the problematic directory when I manually "iterate", but when I use a `for()` loop (in `scrapePerson()`, it errors out (and only for this directory, of the directories I've tried). I appreciate any insights and/or intuitions of where to get started!

Comment: How is anyone suppose to answer this question without seeing any code or sample data? My one tip is to use `dplyr::bind_rows()` instead of `rbind()` it is more robust and less prone to errors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of bind_rows() @Dave2e. And I appreciate the frustration re: the absence of code or sample data. I had considered this, but was not sure how to create a manageably sized reproducible example (as I often do when I ask/answer questions on CV). Would it be considered in bad taste to link to a GitHub repo with the functions and an exemplar data file?

Comment: I would try setting [`options(error = recover)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/recover.html). This will let you enter the function environment at the point the error occurs and inspect current data and objects, which may help you track down the issue. Also see the *Advanced R* [chapter on debugging](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html).